Gitlab upgrade gives problems
I'm upgrading Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 in my Gitlab server and I had to upgrade it using the next commands, exactly as the upgrade manual says:
apt install gitlab-ce=x.x.x-ce.0
My problem now is that I went from 13.0 to 16.3.7 and I can't continue. The printed error in the terminal is the next one:
Preparing to unpack .../gitlab-ce_16.7.0-ce.0_amd64.deb ...
gitlab preinstall: Automatically backing up only the GitLab SQL database (excluding everything else!)
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- gitlab-http
<internal:/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:38:in `require'
<internal:/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:38:in `require'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/initializers/gitlab_http.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:38:in `require'
<internal:/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:38:in `require'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/helpers.rake:7:in `block in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
gitlab preinstall:
gitlab preinstall: Database backup failed! If you want to skip this backup, run the following command and try again:
gitlab preinstall:
gitlab preinstall:  sudo touch /etc/gitlab/skip-auto-backup
gitlab preinstall:
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gitlab-ce_16.7.0-ce.0_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new gitlab-ce package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gitlab-ce_16.7.0-ce.0_amd64.deb
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I'm trying to upgrade to the last version but i cannot go forward.
